# Amazon Elastic Beanstalk, Angular-cli build gzip compression, Nginx, Pagespeed insight says its not compressing

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, gzip, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

How does one get their or angular 2 app to serve content using the .zip files that get built using the angular-cli's production build?

I am an using Elastic Beanstalk load balancer with Nginx and have set enable gzip compression to yes. I use angular-cli and ng build --prod --aot which creates a .bundle.js and .bundle.css gzip zip file with the build which I deployed along with the full js files.

I have run my site through https://checkgzipcompression.com/ and it says I am gzip enabled and would save around 60% from compression.

In configuration -> software -> static files, I added my /dist to Virtual path and Directory, which is my entire angular static content dist folder with all assets where all the .zip files are located.

I wrote an .ebextensions/gzip.config with:

```
files:
  /etc/nginx/conf.d/gzip.conf:
    content: |
      gzip_types 
        text/plain
        text/css
        text/js
        text/xml
        text/javascript
        application/javascript
        application/x-javascript
        application/json
        application/xml
        application/rss+xml
        image/svg+xml;
```

and I am still getting the following error from Google Page Insights:

> Enable compression Compressing resources with gzip or deflate can
>   reduce the number of bytes sent over the network. Enable compression
>   for the following resources to reduce their transfer size by 1.3MiB
>   (76% reduction).

Additional Info:

The folder structure seems that it picks up at / for virtual folder and / seems to be the root of my angular 2 dist folder. I'm not sure where to point Elastic Beanstalks virtual folder and directories because using just / crashed when I tried to upload the config change.

These are the files that are being served, not their .zip versions which angular-cli built using ng build --prod:

> Request 2:
>   .ap-southeast-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/styles.a802cd12df2261411a0e.bundle.css
>   Request 3:
>   .ap-southeast-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/inline.57717eb27b72fe80aa2c.bundle.js
>   Request 4:
>   .ap-southeast-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/scripts.f45e92a6b6c06ec80547.bundle.js
>   Request 5:
>   .ap-southeast-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/vendor.fb1da5e2545e01bc8122.bundle.js
>   Request 6:
>   .ap-southeast-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/main.a8043e44654c4d1e0204.bundle.js

Comment: Spent hours researching this with no luck.

Comment: What EB platform are you using? On the Ruby/Passenger platform at least, the conf files under `/etc/nginx` are not used - the real files are stored under `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/conf`.

Comment: Nodejs - is there an easy way to gain access to the actual folders/files instead of just using .ebextensions. Its a very weird way to try and correct a bug, writing some file which you hope will overwrite some setting.

Comment: I spun up a Nodejs environment, and it looks like gzip compression should be enabled by default. There's a file at `/etc/nginx/conf.d/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf` that already contains the `gzip_types` config, which explains why your new file didn't have any effect. I can't explain why the existing EB config isn't enabling gzip, though...

Comment: How do I find my way to that .conf file and others? Is it somewhere in the amazon API or can I access it with sshing into the load balancer somehow? Yea my server is able to gzip, thats what  https://checkgzipcompression.com/ said, but google page insight says its just not doing it so there must be some setting not working right.

Comment: You should be able to use `eb ssh` to access your web server. AWS does not offer any way to access the load balancer directly, but nginx isn't running on the load balancer.